# Can insert into table * number with same data in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Can insert into table * number with same data in Mysql?(Yes, have same value 3 or 100 times)

```
 INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `test1`, `other_status`, `status`) 
 VALUES ('string', 'KPrBf9', 1, 0) * 3;
```

Comment: What does ` * 3` represent ? What are you trying to achieve ? That is invalid syntax on [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Comment: do you mean to have same value 3 times?
 VALUES ('string', 'KPrBf9', 1, 0)

Comment: Why do you want to add the exact same data three times?

Comment: @fonz Yes, have same value 3 or more than 100 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a stored procedure to insert same statement multiple times:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_loop ( IN nr_input bigint)
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

  my_loop: LOOP
    SET counter=counter+1;

    IF counter=nr_input THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `test1`, `other_status`, `status`) 
    VALUES ('string', 'KPrBf9', 1, 0);

  END LOOP my_loop;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Above procedure will insert same values based on the input parameter you give.

Call the procedure by using:

```
call insert_loop(5); ---number of rows to be inserted
```

Comment: @Akina good point. Updated

Comment: `counter` is excess - you may decrement  `nr_input`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by *3
But if you want to insert multiple records you can use the following

```html
INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `test1`, `other_status`, `status`) 
 VALUES ('string', 'KPrBf9', 1, 0),
('string', 'KPrBf9', 1, 0),
('string', 'KPrBf9', 1, 0);
```

Comment: Do I need three values? what if I have 100 rows

Comment: you can replicate the same pattern

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `INSERT .. VALUES` and study `INSERT .. SELECT` .

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (columns_names)  -- (`name`, `test1`, `other_status`, `status`)
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS amount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT amount + 1 FROM cte WHERE amount < @amount_of_rows_to_insert
)
SELECT 'values list'   -- 'string' AS name, 'KPrBf9' AS test1, 1 AS other_status, 0 AS status
FROM cte;
```

If MySQL version is too old and does not support CTE then

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (columns_names)
SELECT 'values list'
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS amount UNION ALL
       SELECT 2 UNION ALL
       -- ...
       SELECT @amount_of_rows_to_insert ) AS cte;
```